# Cordova injecting wrong implementation into build.gradle. Can I override with build-extras.gradle?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I am maintaining a Cordova plugin that implements the MSAL library in Android and iOS. There is currently a known issue with the com.microsoft.identity.client:msal library in Android on recent Gradle versions (>=8.2 I believe) where, when implementing the MSAL library the normal way via either

plugin.xml

```xml
<framework src="com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:5.0.1" />
```

or build.extras.gradle

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:5.0.1'
```

results in a transitive dependency error upon trying to build:

```
Could not resolve io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.18.0
```

This is a known issue, with further details at [the MSAL's git repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1864)

A fix for that issue has been merged in MSAL's dev branch, but I have no idea when it's going to be rolled out in a public release in Maven. In the meantime, there is a suggested workaround, to exclude that dependency and manually implement it, in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:5.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.opentelemetry'
    }
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api:1.18.0'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-context:1.18.0'
}
```

In my plugin, I put that block in my build-extras.gradle, and made sure that there were no references to MSAL in my plugin.xml. However, building an app with that plugin included still throws that same error as described. I poked around the generated Android project, and realized that, although build-extras.gradle was being properly used, installing the plugin also inserted the following in the base  auto-generated build.gradle:

```
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:5.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

If I remove that second implementation and rebuild, it builds and runs just fine, as it uses the dependency declared in build-extras.gradle. However, this isn't feasible in the real world for obvious reasons. Is there a way I can either prevent this line from being written, remove it, or otherwise fix this issue?

Thank you all for your help and support!